# Cannot read property Collation.This property is not available on SQL Server 7.0

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, smo

I'm not able to add administrator role in SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I try to add new user it throws me the following error:

> Cannot read property Collation.This property is not available on SQL Server 7.0. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo).

Comment: Something a bit odd is happening here. You say you're using SQL Server 2008 R2. That's version 10, I think. Version 7 is the version prior to SQL Server 2000. What version have you got? Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: As suprising as it might be, but I think I found a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635539/error-adding-login-with-ssms-2008

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this today. I tried to connect to a **SQL Server 2014 instance** while using **SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2**. This is exactly the same error I got:

> Cannot read property Collation.This property is not available on SQL Server 7.0. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo).

Installing SSMS 2014 did the trick; I can connect and add users fine.