# cannot read property user access. this property is not available on sql server 7.0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to know the **.mdf file** path from property tab of a db, but it was throwing error as

> cannot read property user access. this property is not available on
>   sql server 7.0

Note : on querying my version of SSMS is `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64)   Apr 20 2015 17:29:27   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`

My DB administrator says I have all the access for the same. yet I don't know why this is happening? Please adjust any alternatives for knowing the .mdf file details.

Comment: Share the SQL Server version and the SSMS version. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635539/error-adding-login-with-ssms-2008    https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57466/cannot-read-property-collation-this-property-is-not-available-on-sql-server-7-0

Comment: "sql server 7.0"  How are you trying to determine this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to identify the file path with the following query in SSMS:

```
SELECT file_id, type_desc, physical_name
FROM sys.database_files;
```

Comment: yeah thank you very much..! but what about error :cannot read property user access. this property is not available on sql server 7.0

Comment: No idea. What version of SSMS are you using? Or are you using a different tool?